# I have 2 ULs next to each other, one appears on hover; but cannot move mouse over to it fast enough

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a horizontal menu, and when you hover on an item a vertical menu appears below it (menu2). When hovering on an item in menu 2, a third menu appears next to menu2 at the same height as the item being hovered on in menu 2.
http://gcommerce2.gtdsites.com/ (it is the menu I am building right below where it says "home page")
I got it all working. The item you hover on in menu2 to reveal menu3 is "submenu2". The only problem is that when you move the mouse over to try and select one of the items in menu 3, everything disappears before you can get the mouse onto menu 3.
Here is the code:

```
<style>
nav a { 
text-decoration: none;
font: 12px/1 Verdana;
color: #000;
display: block; }
nav a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
nav ul { 
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }
nav ul li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/* Top-level menu */
nav > ul > li { 
float: left;
position: relative; }
nav > ul > li > a { 
padding: 10px 30px;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
display: block;}
nav > ul > li:first-child { margin: 0; }
nav > ul > li:first-child a { border: 0; }

/* Dropdown Menu */
nav ul li ul { 
position: absolute;
background: #ccc;
width: 100%; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: none; }
nav ul li ul li { 
text-align: center;
width: 100%; }
nav ul li ul a { padding: 10px 0; }
nav ul li:hover ul { display: block; }


a.menu2:link + ul.menu3 {display: none;}
a.menu2:hover + ul.menu3 {display: inline-block; }

.format_text ul ul {
margin: 0 0 0 .95em;
}

a.menu2, li.menu2 {display: inline-block;}

ul.menu2, ul.menu3 {border: black 2px solid;}


</style>

<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Link2</a>
        <ul class="menu2">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>

            <li class="menu2"><a class="menu2" href="#">Submenu2</a>



            <ul class="menu3">
            <li><a class="menu3" href="#">gmenu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">gmenu22</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">gmenu3</a></li>

            </ul>





            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu3</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>

<br style="clear:both;"/>
```

Can Anyone help with this?

Comment: For demonstrations of your front-end problem please post the relevent *minimal* / [sscce](http://sscce.org/) HTML/CSS/JavaScript (whatever you're using) to a site on which we can easily *see*, and *edit*, the code, such as [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), [CSS Desk](http://cssdesk/), [Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the http://jqueryui.com/menu/ plugin. It's much easier than trying to code your own menu structure

`example` http://jsfiddle.net/h7N5R/

Comment: Thanks for including this andrew; i have looked it over and its cool; one thing i noticed that on the items that have a menu that appears on the side of them; that there is a blank line below them all; tried to see if i could get rid of that; but so far no luck; still working on this...

Answer (score 0):

You want to be targeting hover on the list item not the anchor tag

Change

```
a.menu2:hover + ul.menu3 {display: inline-block; }
```

To

```
li.menu2:hover > ul.menu3 {display: inline-block; }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/VdqnD/

Comment: Thank you so much Jon!  Somehow I missed your little code snippet when I tried this before and could not get it to work.  Been a very frustrating day trying all kinds of crap and no luck.  So I thought I would come back here once more just to check things out and I saw your code snippet; and I was like "that wasnt there before"...

Comment: suffice to say i did what you said and it is working great now, so thanks so much!  g